# How to prevent calling the onTap of parent widget when the child widget is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SizedBox` widget that occupies the whole width of the screen, and it has a child widget that has around 400px of width. When the `SizedBox` is clicked, I'm calling the `Navigator.pop` to go back to previous page. but I don't want that to be called when the child widget is clicked. Currently, when I click the child widget, it also calls the `onTap` function of the parent widget. How can I prevent that?

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    print("GestureDetector Outer");
    final isDismissible = ModalRoute.of(context)?.barrierDismissible;
    if (isDismissible == true) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  },
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.maxFinite,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 400,
          child: _content(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with wrapping your child widget in to `IgnorePointer` widget.

Comment: IgnorePointer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

You need to wrap your child widget with gesturedetector. also you can use IgnorePointer widget.

```
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("GestureDetector Outer");
        final isDismissible =
            ModalRoute.of(context)?.barrierDismissible;
        if (isDismissible == true) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(  // wrap your child widget with gesturedetector or IgnorePointer widget
              onTap: () {},
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 400,
                child: _content(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: GestureDetector works but IgnorePointer doesn't

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation @AlRyanAcain